# How do I autocomplete each line in textarea starting from 3rd word in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have an array of ingredients like this:

```
var ingredients = ["Olive Oil", "Parmesan Cheese", "Salt"];
```

I have a text area, and I want each of the lines to be autocompleted with one of the ingredients. For example, if I type "Ol", it should suggest olive oil.

But, each of the lines should be auto completed starting from the 3rd word.

For example, the first line in the text area may be: 4 tbsp Olive Oil.

The first word is the quantity, the second word is the unit, so the auto complete for the ingredient must start at the third word for each line in the text area.

How would I go about doing this?
Please help, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you **know** the string will always have at least 3 words like you said (qty, unit, ingredient), you can get the ingredient quick an easily like so.

```js
var str = '4 tbsp Olive Oil';

var ingredient = str.split(' ').splice(2).join(' ')

alert(ingredient);
```

> What this does is split the phrase up by word (split on space), removes the first 2 words, then joins it back together so you can use it in autocomplete.

Comment: How would I use it with autocomplete though?

Comment: Where is your autocomplete code? What have you tried?

Comment: Can you give me an example using autocomplete in a text area where each line is autocompleted? That would be very helpful. I have tried using Jquery Autocomplete, but that is not working